# Get background color from custom field?

Tags: php, css

I'm using the Meta Slider from wordpress, and the admin page adds two options to the slider which are "Caption" and "URL" I want to add the "Background Color" option to the fields and have the LI class call the background color from the field. How would I do this.

Here is the php for the slider where the fields are located, how and where do i add the "Background Color" option.

https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/7621697

also what do I add to the css for it to call from the background field?

Answer (score 0):

```
 // localise the JS
        wp_localize_script( 'metaslider-admin-script', 'metaslider', array( 
            'url' => __("URL", 'metaslider'), 
            'caption' => __("Caption", 'metaslider'),

            /* ADD */'Background Color' => __("Background Color", 'metaslider'),

            'new_window' => __("New Window", 'metaslider'),
            'confirm' => __("Are you sure?", 'metaslider'),
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'resize_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('metaslider_resize'),
            'iframeurl' => METASLIDER_BASE_URL . 'preview.php',
            'useWithCaution' => __("Caution: This setting is for advanced developers only. If you're unsure, leave it checked.", 'metaslider')
        ));
```

also line 144

```
 * Media Manager iframe HTML
 */
public function iframe() {
    wp_enqueue_style('metaslider-admin-styles', METASLIDER_ASSETS_URL . 'metaslider/admin.css', false, METASLIDER_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_script('google-font-api', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700');

    $link = apply_filters('metaslider_hoplink', 'http://www.metaslider.com/upgrade/');
    $link .= '?utm_source=lite&utm_medium=more-slide-types&utm_campaign=pro';

    echo "<div class='metaslider'>";
    echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 50px;'>Get the Pro Addon pack to add support for: <b>Post Feed</b> Slides, <b>YouTube</b> Slides, <b>HTML</b> Slides & <b>Vimeo</b> Slides</p>";
    echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;'><b>NEW: </b> Animated HTML <b>Layer</b> Slides (with an awesome Drag & Drop editor!)</p>";
    echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;'><b></b> Live Theme Editor!</p>";
    echo "<p style='text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;'><b>NEW:</b> Thumbnail Navigation for Flex & Nivo Slider!</p>";
    echo "<a class='probutton' href='{$link}' target='_blank'>Get <span class='logo'><strong>Meta</strong>Slider</span><span class='super'>Pro</span></a>";
    echo "<span class='subtext'>Opens in a new window</span>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: @user32447 I've resolved issues in user2840324's code, please see the `/* ADD */` comment to see what he's asking you to add.

Comment: @ohgodwhy i have added that but it still doesn't show up as a field :(